# My model ids collide with cids ( eg: "c7" )

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbone.

After much confusion about not being able to add some of my models to a collection and sometimes getting the wrong model using `collection.get(id)` I found out that my model ids are colliding with backbones cids.

My model ids are something like "c7" or "c5e6". While the later is no problem "c7" is backbones own cid for the seventh element of the collection.

So if I ask for `collection.get('c7')` and expect `null` I instead get the element that was  given the cid "c7" by backbone. And if I add an element with id "c7" I will never get it back with `get("c7")`.

I wonder if I am the first one with this problem, I did not find anything about a syntax restriction of backbone ids, is there a way to solve this? As a workaround I will save my own ids in a custom attribute, and have to use `collection.where` instead of `collection.get`.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this does look like an edge case problem with no real solution. Looking at the Backbone source, we can see in the `Backbone.Collection.set` method that Backbone mixes both your IDs and their internal CIDs in the same object:

```
set: function(models, options) {
  // ...
  this._byId[model.cid] = model;
  if (model.id != null) this._byId[model.id] = model;
  // ...
  return this;
},
```

The `_byId` object holds all IDs which causes your issue. Here is the `Backbone.Collection.get` method:

```
get: function(obj) {
  if (obj == null) return void 0;
  return this._byId[obj.id != null ? obj.id : obj.cid || obj];
},
```

When you call it using a non-existent ID (of your own) like "c7", the `return ...` line becomes `return this._byId["c7"];`. Since `_byId` has references to yours and Backbone's IDs, you're getting their entry returned when you expected `null`.

[nikoshr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071630/nikoshr) has a great solution in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657953/1160937).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [Backbone source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-29), you will see that the `cid` in a model is determined in the constructor by

```
this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
```

*c* is an arbitrary prefix which means you could disambiguate your ids by overriding `_.uniqueId`, something like

```
_._uniqueId = _.uniqueId;
_.uniqueId = function(prefix) {
    if (prefix === 'c') {
        prefix = 'cc';
    }
    return _._uniqueId(prefix);
};
```

Without the override : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/KmNSr/ and with it : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/KmNSr/1/